# prove that , there is no element $a , b$ of the group $G$ which satisfy this property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

let $G=(x) \times (y) $ where $(t)$ is the group generated by $t$  , $|x|= 8 , |y|=4$

let $H=(x^2y , y^2 )$ be isomorphic to $Z_4 \times Z_2 $

prove that , there are no elements a,b of G such that $G=(a) \times (b)$ and 
$H = (a^2) \times (b^2)$

any hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $G/H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4$ but $\big((a)\times(b)\big)/\big((a^2)\times(b^2)\big)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: i think there is a problem  ! because i think that  $G/H$ is isomorphic to $Z_2 \times Z_2$ , proof , $Z_4$ is normal subgroup of $Z_8$ because the index = 2 similarly $Z_2$ is normal subgroup of $Z_4$ , so $(Z_8 \times Z_4) / (Z_4 \times Z_2)$ is isomorphic to $Z_8/Z_4 \times Z_4/Z_2 $is isomorphic to  $Z_2 \times Z_2$

Comment: @MathsLover: For $G=(x)\times(y)$, $H$ is **only isomorphic** to $\mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_2$, but **not equal** to $(x^2)\times (y^2)$, so you cannot obtain an isomorphism between $G/H$ and $(\mathbb Z_8\times \mathbb Z_4)/(\mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_2)$.

Comment: @MathsLover: However, since $|G|=32$ and since $|H|=8$, $G/H$ is a group of order $4$. You can check that $G/H$ is generated by a single element $xH$, i.e. $G/H$ is a cyclic group of order $4$.

Comment: when two groups are isomorphic , we can deal them similarly as having the same algebraic structure , right ? $H$ is isomorphic to $Z_4 \times Z_2$ so we can deal with $H$ as $Z_4 \times Z_2$ , am i right ?

Comment: @MathsLover: You must be careful when considering quotient groups. For example, if $G=\mathbb Z$ and $H=2\mathbb Z$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $G/H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$. Note that although $H$ is isomorphic to $G$, you cannot conclude that $G/H$ is isomorphic to $G/G$. By the way, the notation $(\mathbb Z_8\times \mathbb Z_4)/(\mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_2)$ in my last comment is not rigorous, because $\mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_2$ is even not a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_8\times \mathbb Z_4$. What I exactly meant was $((x)\times(y))/((x^2)\times(y^2))$.

Comment: so , in genral , if $H$ , $K$ are  normal subgroups of G and $H$ is isomorphic to $K$ then it's not necessary true that , $G/H$ is isomorphic to $G/K$ ?  , i think that my method works to prove that $((a) \times (b))/((a^2) \times (b^2))$ is isomorphic to $Z_2 \times Z_2$ , right ? as $(a^2)$ is normal subgroup of $(a)$ and also is $(b^2)$ is a normal subgroup of $(b)$

Comment: @MathsLover: I think both of your statements are correct. Can you  complete the solution to your original question with my hint now?

Comment: hmmm , how can i show that $xH$ generates $G/H$ ? i mean , $H$ is defined as $(x^2y , y^2)$ but $G$ is a direct product of two groups , so how can we understand the definition of $H$ ?

Comment: @MathsLover: All the elements $G$ can be written as $x^iy^j$, $0\le i\le 7$, $0\le j\le 3$. $H$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by two elements $x^2y$ and $y^2$. You have known that $G/H$ is a group of order $4$, so each element in $G/H$ is of order $1$, $2$ or $4$. Then to show $G/H$ is generated by $xH$, it suffices to show that $x^2H\ne H$, i.e. $x^2\notin H$. I hope you can show this by yourself.

Comment: thanx :) it's done now :D , thank for your great help .

Comment: @MathsLover: You are welcome.