# How does this strange phenomena happen in quotient of groups ?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

in my question , [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411527/prove-that-there-is-no-element-a-b-of-the-group-g-which-satisfy-this-pro) , i learned a strange fact from the comments which was a surprise for me on the answer of landsacpe  !

and this surprise it :

if $G$ is a group , $H$ and $K$ are two normal subgroups of $G$ such that  $H$ is isomorphic to K then 
it is NOT necessary true that $G/H$ is isomorphic to $G/K$ .

i always thought that two isomorphic groups have the same algebraic structure and so we can deal with them as the same things , we can use them respectively in fact !

but an example from the member Landscape broke down this thought

so , why does this happens in quotients groups ? why two groups have the same isomorophism type leads to different  groups under quotients ?

also , in which case , two isomorophism groups may leads to different things ? and in which case there is no matter to deal with them as the same thing ?

till the moment , i think this phenomena may happens ONLY on infinite groups not finite groups " it may not happen also in infinite generated groups i think ! "

any clarification plz ?

Comment: Two subgroups being isomorphic means that they have the same "internal" structure, that is, multiplying and inversing elements of the subgroups behave exactly the same. The thing is, quotienting by a subgroup relates as much to the internal structure of the subgroup as to the elements outside it. A simple example is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ versus $\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z$. Although $2\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, if you look at them as subgroups of $\mathbb Z$, they don't play the same role (obviously).

Comment: In the linked question, following your notations there, $G$ is finite and $H$ is isomorphic to $K=(x^2)\times(y^2)$, but $G/H$ is not isomorphic to $G/K$.

Comment: @Landscape , great , thanx :) , let me ask you plz another question ! if $G_1$ is isomorphic  to $G_2$ and $H_1$ is normal of $G_1$ and $H_2$ is normal of $G_2$ and $H_1$ is isomorphic to $H_2$ , is it necessary true that $G_1/H_1$ is isomorphic to $G_2/H_2$ ? i mean , does the phenomena in the question happen only when the two normal subgroups are subgroups of the same group ? or also happens when they are in different but isomorphic groups ?

Comment: @MathsLover: $G_1=G_2$ is simply a special case of $G_1$ isomorphic to $G_2$, so the same phenomenon happens.

Comment: @Brian , i don't understand what you try to say .

Comment: Let $G_1 = \mathbb{Z}$, $G_2 = 2\mathbb{Z}$, $H_1 = 3\mathbb{Z}$, and $H_2 = 2\mathbb{Z}$, to see that the claim is false.

Comment: If there exists $\vartheta\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ such that $\vartheta(H)=K$, then $\vartheta$ induces an isomorphism $G/H\cong G/K$.

Comment: @WarrenMoore , yes , this is what Ittay talked about in the answer but in the language of categories.

Comment: @MathsLover Ahh I didn't actually see that... My mistake!

Comment: @WarrenMoore , no ! your comment is also useful for me . no need to say a mistake  , thank you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The quotient of two groups is an operation on a group and one of its subgroups. The way that the subgroup sits inside the bigger group is relevant here. Looking just at the subgroup and replacing it with an isomorphic copy of it inside the bigger group may change the way that the smaller group sits inside the bigger one. As a simple example, consider $G=\mathbb Z_3\times S_3$. Now, consider the two subgroups $H=\mathbb Z_3\times \{e\}$ and $K=\{e\}\times \{e,(123),(132)\}$. Both are normal and isomorphic to each other. But $G/H\cong S_3$ while $G/K\cong \mathbb Z_3\times \mathbb Z_2$.

In short, isomorphic objects can safely be interchanged (always with your eyes open though) inside the category where they are isomorphic. Once a construction is occurring outside of that category you can't just treat things that are isomorphic in some category as the same. When the category changes, the notion of isomorphism changes. In the case above, if you consider the category whose objects are $(G,H)$ where $G$ is a group and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and arrows $(G,H)\to (G',H')$ are group homomorphisms $\psi :G\to G'$ such that the restriction of $\psi$ to $H$ lands in $H'$, then isomorphic objects here will have isomorphic quotients. The quotient operation here becomes a functor from this category $C$ to the category $Grp$ of groups.

In this category, for $(G,H)$ and $(G',H')$ to be isomorphic means that there is a group isomorphism $\psi:G\to G'$ such that the restriction of it to $H$ is an isomorphism onto $H'$. This says exactly that the isomorphism does not just change the names of the elements of the subgroups, but also the names of the elements of the bigger groups, and in such a way that everything is consistent. The counter example I gave above shows that $(\mathbb Z_3\times S_3, \mathbb Z_3\times \{e\})$ is not isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z_3\times S_3,\{e\}\times \{e,(123),(132)\})$.

Comment: thanks :) ,how can i know more about those things named categories ? category theory ?

Comment: the book "abstract and concret categories" is available online. Mac Lane's "Categories for the working mathematician" is still extremely good compared to many other modern texts. Having said that, there are lots of other sources you can find.

Comment: +1. One should remark that the quotient group is *not* a functor on the category of pairs of two abstract groups, but rather on the category of $(G,H,i)$ where $i : H \to G$ is a normal embedding. If $(G,H) \cong (G',H')$, there is no reason why $(G,H,i) \cong (G',H',i')$.

Answer (score 7):

Some other examples that may help you:

- $G_1\cong G_2=\mathbb Z$, $H_1=2\mathbb Z\cong3\mathbb Z=H_2$ but $\mathbb Z_2=G/H_1\ncong G/H_2=\mathbb Z_3 $.
- $G_1\cong G_2=D_8$ and $H_1=\langle a\rangle\ncong H_2=\{e,a^2,b,a^2b\}$ but $D_8/H_1\cong D_8/H_2$.

Comment: nice examples +1

Comment: Nice examples, indeed $+\uparrow$

Comment: Hi Babak! It is my good fortune to have stayed up long enough to see YOU visit before I retire for the evening!

Comment: @amWhy: And that's why I feel my Sun shines on me here. Thanks Amyyyyy ;-)

Comment: :^) $\;\ddot\smile$